# How to test a if a BST is balanced after its constructed from sorted array

Tags: algorithm, testing, data-structures, tree

I have created a Balanced BST from a sorted array, my question is how to test it.  Simply testing that if a tree is balanced or not will not help, as even a binary tree (note - mentioned Binary tree, not BST) can be balanced. Testing if a tree is BST is also not enof. Only answer I have now, is to check if it is `balanced' &&`bst`. Now this is a complicated 2 step testing process. Any simple / smarter solution ?

Comment: What property do you want to test? That the nodes are sorted? When you say "test if is balanced", then that test should only check balancedness - which is perfectly fine. Indeed, a BST might need to fulfill multiple different tests (which is *not* complicated, but just a `&&` conjunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's balanced than it's depth will be at most log(n)+1 where n is the number of nodes in the tree/array.

Checking if the tree is indeed BST can be done simply by traversing the nodes "in order" and making sure they really are in order.

By the way, if you have a sorted array, there's a very easy way to build a balanced BST out of it, you run the same way you do in binary search - only with the "inserts" and applying "both sides" of the search. For example, say you have:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

You start by inserting `5`, followed by `3` and `7`, followed by the rest.

Comment: Thanks but question is is there any shorter technique than doing to `test` than doing 2 different checks 1 for BST and the other for binary ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper when you traverse "in order" you can check height too - no need for two traverses.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

There is a very [good article](http://techieme.in/binary-search-tree-basics/) you can read, it is all about relations between BST and Sorted array in particular.

Still to answer it in brief, a BST can show all kind of nuisances, if you do not choose to build it wisely, had it been the case where the array is not sorted, the best guarantee for a balanced BST is when it is built randomly. Watch the video from Eric Domaine ([Randomly built BSTs](http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_demaine_lec09/))

Now that you already have built a BST out of sorted array then what suggested in the alfasin [ depth is at most log(n) + 1] is a good check... But I would like to disagree because when you talk about the max depth it is like checking each node and storing it into some space, because you won't know the deepest node and so I find it tough when you have a huge tree.

I would suggest finding the height of the root. If the height of the root is log(n) + 1 it is balanced.

Let the program do all the storing of calculated values in stack.